# NGINX uri with parameter in named location

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

i have multiple upstreams for https request and for socket connection.

My problem is i can't get it to work with uri with a parameter, i always get NOT FOUND.

Example i want to proxy pass to :xxxxxxxx.solana-mainnet.discover.quiknode.pro/19a23aa44e703b2ee18ac2eeaadxxxxxxxxxx

I have tried rewites and etc ... looked on stackoverflow but can't find the solution.

My current conf is :

```
upstream socketreq {
    server xxxxxxxx.solana-mainnet.discover.quiknode.pro;
    server api.mainnet-beta.solana.com backup;
}
upstream httpsreq {
    server xxxxxxxx.solana-mainnet.discover.quiknode.pro;
    server solana-api.projectserum.com backup;
    server api.mainnet-beta.solana.com backup;
}
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name api-snipe-node.net;
    client_max_body_size 100m;
    location / {
        try_files /nonexistent @$http_upgrade;
    }
    location @websocket {
        # rewrite /19a23aa44e703b2ee18ac2eeaadxxxxxxxxxx last; doesn't work
        # rewrite @websocket /19a23aa44e703b2ee18ac2eeaadxxxxxxxxxx last; doesn't work
        # proxy_pass http://socketreq/19a23aa44e703b2ee18ac2eeaadxxxxxxxxxx; doesn't work
        proxy_pass http://socketreq;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    location @ {
        # rewrite  /19a23aa44e703b2ee18ac2eeaadxxxxxxxxxx last; last doesn't work
        # rewrite @ /19a23aa44e703b2ee18ac2eeaadxxxxxxxxxx last; last doesn't work
        # proxy_pass http://httpsreq/19a23aa44e703b2ee18ac2eeaadxxxxxxxxxx; doesn't work
        proxy_pass http://httpsreq;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
    error_page  500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you make use of all the internal locations using `@`? That does not make sense. And is this `19a23aa44e703b2ee18ac2eeaadxxxxxxxxxx` a static uri segment on your upstream server or will that change? if not simply add this at the end of your `proxy_pass`  and what is this `try_files` doing for you?

Comment: @TimoStark it's because i want to have websockets and https request on the same url. 
Also 19a23aa44e703b2ee18ac2eeaadxxxxxxxxxx this is static.
I added it on end of my proxy pass but it gives me error.

Comment: I would simply handle the upgrade part with an map but a single location block will be just fine. Take a look here. https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/